# Having a legend causes IE to ignore the top padding of a fieldset - alternatives?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, padding, legend, fieldset

I'm creating a form and ran into a padding problem with fieldsets. While all looks ok in Opera, FF and Chrome, both IE 7 and 8 simply throw away any top padding inside the fieldset. The following code correctly adds padding to the left, bottom and right of the fielset (although the latter causes this [known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248483/ie-css-fieldset-border-extends-too-far-to-the-right-why)), but positions the first line of content directly underneath the legend with no spacing:

```
<form>      
  <fieldset style="padding:30px;">
      <legend>Legend</legend>
      <label for="input">Label</label>
      <input type="text" id="input" />  
  </fieldset>    
 </form>
```

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398861/840977) to another question pointed me towards the legend tag and indeed, if I leave it out, everything is fine.

So my question is:

Is there a work-around to have both the legend tag and the padding? My quick top-of-the hat attempt (margin-top on the first element) does not have an effect.

Or do I have to forego the (semantically correct) legend tag and replace it with something (more arbitrary) like a heading? What concequences does this have for screen-readers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it work to remove all the padding from the fieldset and instead create a div inside the fieldset that adds the padding?

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
      <legend>Legend</legend>
      <div style="padding:30px;">
         <label for="input">Label</label>
         <input type="text" id="input" />
      </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. I'll just have to see if I can get my framework guru to... well... adjust the framework so that it generates this nested structure when rendering the page... I'll leave the question open for a day or two, just in case, okay? ;)